# can we use both virtual and new keyword in methods of c#?

Tags: c#, function

can we use both virtual and new keyword in methods of c#?

Comment: What happened when you tried to declare such a method?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. You would be defining a method that hid a method of a parent and allowed children to override. The behavior might be a little strange though. Say you had the following classes:

```
public class A
{
    public void DoSomething(){ Console.WriteLine("42!"); }
}

public class B : A
{
    public virtual new void DoSomething(){ Console.WriteLine("Not 42!"); }
}

public class C : B
{
    public override void DoSomething(){ Console.WriteLine("43!"); }
}
```

Then your execution would look something like:

```
A a = new A();
A bAsA = new B();
A cAsA = new C();
B b = new B();
B cAsB = new C();
C c = new C();

a.DoSomething(); // 42!

b.DoSomething(); // Not 42!
bAsA.DoSomething(); // 42!

c.DoSomething(); // 43!
cAsB.DoSomething(); // 43!
cAsA.DoSomething(); // 42!
```

Comment: So, can we say that the "new" keyword in "B"s method says something like "Only use this implementation if the Instance is created of my specific type (B), and not of my parent type (A)? or is that just a coincidence...

Comment: @funkymushroom no, it means 'only use this implementation if the code is working with my specific type'. Notice bAsA says 42!, but the instance is of type B / what's different is that it's being accessed as something of type A.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can combine both.

`virtual` allows a method to be overridden in a derived class

`new` allows you to hide the old method.

Both are complementary and not contradicting.

Answer (score 1):

Don't hesitate to just try this yourself, Visual Studio makes it easy.

```
class Base {
    public virtual void Method() { }
}
class Derived : Base {
    public virtual new void Method() { }
}
```